# What does E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) mean?

Tags: java, android

Can someone please explain to me what 
E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) actually means?

Im getting this error in android studio.

Comment: JVMTI is a debugging and profiling protocol. I guess it's expecting some thread to be alive while it's not.

Comment: @Anatolii is this a bug for my Application or Android Studio ?

Answer (score 0):

JVMTI is the debugging and profiling protocol. 
So, I'm thinking it's something related to the environment you are attempting to run your application in.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get rid of this error by restarting the tablet/emulator I was testing on